# Powershell: Switch and If on $null valued variable behaving diffrently

Tags: powershell, if-statement, null, switch-statement

I do not know why my switch-statemant won't evaluate the `default` branch:

```
function Test-Function {
    [CmdletBinding()]param()
    $stage = Get-ItemProperty -Path $REGISTRY_KEY -Name $FRUIT_VALUE -ErrorAction Ignore

    if ($null -eq $stage) {
        "`$stage is `$null."
        #$stage = $null
    }
    
    switch ($stage) {
        "apple"  {"We found an apple"; break}
        "pear"   {"We found a pear"; break}
        "orange" {"We found an orange"; break}
        "peach"  {"We found a peach"; break}
        "banana" {"We found a banana"; break}
        default {"Something else happened"; break}
     }
}
```

`Get-ItemProperty` returns `$null` because the registry value is missing. As one would expect I get `$stage is $null.` as an output. But strangely the output won't display `Something else happened`. If I do set  `$stage = $null` (line 7) although it's already `$null` I do get the desired output:

```
$stage is $null.
Something else happened
```

What am I missing?

## Further minification

```
function Test-Function {
    [CmdletBinding()]param()
    $txt = (Get-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\does\not" -Name "exist" -ErrorAction Ignore)

    if ($null -eq $txt) {
        "if: `$null"
        # $txt = $null
    }
    
    switch ($txt) {
        "test"  {"switch: TEST"}
        $null   {"switch: `$null"}
        default {"switch: DEFAULT"}
     }
}
```

Neither `switch: $null` nor `switch: DEFAULT` appears as output but `if: $null` does. How come?

Comment: Because `$null` and `AutomationNull.Value` are not the same thing.

Comment: Ok so `$stage` is `AutomationNull.Value`(?) and `if` seems to auto-convert to `$null` during comparison? But why does `default` not match `AutomationNull.Value` when nothing else matches.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/deep-dives/everything-about-null?view=powershell-7.2#empty-null see this

Comment: The link should already explain why this doesn't work, this is like trying to `switch(@()) { ... }` or `switch(& { }) { ... }` there is nothing to switch on.

Answer (score 0):

> Also, be careful with empty returns from cmdlets. Cmdlets or pipelines that have no output are treated as an empty array that does not match anything, including the default case.

```
$file = Get-ChildItem NonExistantFile*
switch ( $file )
{
    $null   { '$file is $null' }
    default { "`$file is type $($file.GetType().Name)" }
}
# No matches
```

Taken from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/deep-dives/everything-about-switch?view=powershell-7.2#null)

Comment: But this is exaclty my problem: I do wan't to match `default` if (in you case) `$file` matches nothing else.

Comment: Since this is a documented behavior, I guess the only thing you can do here is to raise an issue to devs and use the workaround.